# can't continue script from .bat file after closing msgbox

Tags: batch-file, terminal, msgbox

I have a script that saves 2 files in a backup folder. I want to get a message box if the copy command was successful or not.

```
@echo off
Echo msgbox"Saving test1 to \backup directory." + vbNewLine + "Successfull!",0,"Backup file..">test1.vbs
Echo msgbox"Saving test2 to \backup directory." + vbNewLine + "Successfull!",0,"Backup file..">test2.vbs

copy test1.txt backup\test1.txt
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
    start test1.vbs
    goto test2
)else (
    echo ## Errorausgabe: %ERRORLEVEL%
    echo.
)

:test2
copy test2.txt backup\test2.txt
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0(
    start test2.vbs
    goto commonexit
)else(
echo ## Errorausgabe: %ERRORLEVEL%
)

:commonexit
pause
```

It works till i get the message box from test1. But when I click submit the test2 doesnt start. What's the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

In this line you omit a space `if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0(` should be `if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (` and in this line too `)else (` should be `) else (`

Try like this :

```bat
@echo off
Echo msgbox"Saving test1 to \backup directory." + vbNewLine + "Successfull!",0,"Backup file..">test1.vbs
Echo msgbox"Saving test2 to \backup directory." + vbNewLine + "Successfull!",0,"Backup file..">test2.vbs

copy test1.txt backup\test1.txt
if "%ERRORLEVEL%" EQU "0" (
    start test1.vbs
    goto test2
) else (
    echo ## Errorausgabe: %ERRORLEVEL%
    echo.
)

:test2
copy test2.txt backup\test2.txt
if "%ERRORLEVEL%" EQU "0" (
    start test2.vbs
    goto commonexit
) else (
echo ## Errorausgabe: %ERRORLEVEL%
)

:commonexit
pause
```

https://ss64.com/nt/if.html

Comment: @nolags please check it again i edit my answer, and i test it the MsgBox is showing for me  !

Comment: it prints a compatibility problem in vbscript .. he is waiting for a command finish for the test2.vbs

Comment: @nolags why not try call instead of start?

Comment: still opens the test1.vbs but then writes an error at skript test2.vbs lin1 char 70 with the problem: waiting for instruction end Code 800A0401.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was he couldn't find the tes2.vbs file. added %tmp%\ as directory path for the vbs files! Now it works.